# Security Restrictions Downloading From the Internet

Tags: windows, security, group-policy, internet-explorer-7

For some reason since we rolled out IE7 to the estate users are unable to download from the Internet, they get an error message "the operation could not be completed due to restrictions on the computer" I have checked the GPO and it allows downloads in the Default domain policy. I am I missing something in GPO or is this problem with IE7.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Are there any other browsers installed on this machines?

Comment: No other browsers are installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310049/en-us) article.

"After you upgrade to Microsoft Internet Explorer 6 or to Internet Explorer 7, the following registry key is either missing or corrupted:
HKEY_Local_Machine\Software\Classes\htmlfile\shell\open\command"

"To resolve this issue, import the registry key from another computer."

-Josh